# Calculated field in Sharepoint Lists when some of the text fields are empty

Tags: calculated-column

I am trying to create a calculated field that produces a person's full name in the following format:

"1stLastname 2ndLastName, FName MName".

I am using the following formula, but keep getting an error:

```
=[CL-1stLName]&" "&IF(ISBLANK([CL-2ndLName]);"";[CL-2ndLName])&", "&[CL-FName]&" "&IF(ISBLANK([CL-MName]);"";[CL-MName])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

```
=[CL-1stLName]&" "&IF(ISBLANK([CL-2ndLName]),"",[CL-2ndLName])&", "&[CL-FName]&" "&IF(ISBLANK([CL-MName]),"",[CL-MName])
```

[image]